# Show overlay when button click

Tags: swift, button, mapkit, overlay

I am a new developer. I want to track user movement by button e.g. when tapping button MapKit show overlay or user movement.
I have this code:

```
var mapOverlay: MKTileOverlay!
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        if overlay is MKPolyline {
            let polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red
            polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 3
            return polylineRenderer
        }
        return MKOverlayRenderer()
    }
    @IBAction func start(_ sender: Any) { 
   let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = mapView.userLocation.coordinate
            annotation.subtitle = "Start"
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```